# ¿Cómo poner los valores de una array en un textfield en Java?

Tags: java, array, jframe, jtextfield

Quiero que se muestre un en un textfield cada vez que se presione un botón un array de letras basado en la cantidad deseada, ejemplo: cantidad deseada: 3, letra seleccionada "A" por lo tanto el array será algo así: AAA. Sin embargo el textfield solo muestra una vez la letra. Esta sería la función de add

```
public void add()
{
    int tam = Integer.parseInt(tLength.getText()); 
    
    String val = (String) procList.getSelectedItem();
    
    int offset = 7 - tam;
    
    String [] cola = new String[7];
    
    String line;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {
        cola[i] = val;
        
        line = String.valueOf(cola[i]);
        System.out.println(cola[i]);
        t1.setText(line);
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes concatenar el valor de `val` en la variable `line` dentro del for. Luego agregar esa cadena al campo de texto:

```
public void add()
    {
        String val = (String) procList.getSelectedItem();

        int tam = Integer.parseInt(tLength.getText()); 
        
        String line;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
        {
            line += val;
            
        }
        t1.setText(line);
        
    }
```

> Sin embargo el textfield solo muestra una vez la letra

Eso se debe a se está llamando `t1.setText()` dentro del for, eso hace que se sobreescriba el valor que fue colocado antes. Para que funcione primero se debe extraer el valor del campo de texto y concatenar el nuevo valor:

```
public void add()
{
    int tam = Integer.parseInt(tLength.getText()); 
    
    String val = (String) procList.getSelectedItem();
    
    int offset = 7 - tam;
    
    String [] cola = new String[7];
    
    String line;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {
        cola[i] = val;
        
        line = String.valueOf(cola[i]);
        System.out.println(cola[i]);
        // obtener el valor actual y concatenar el nuevo valor
        t1.setText(t1.getText() + line);
    }
      
}
```